# Anonymous inner class -- getting "this"

Tags: java, this, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

I know that if I have an anonymous inner class and I need the outer class instance, I would just use Outer.this.  However, I have an anon class within an anon class, and I want the instance of the latter (the outer anonymous class).

Example:

```
mRestService.getComicLatest(new Callback<Comic>() {

    @Override
    public void success(Comic comic, Response response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        mRetryFrame.findViewById(R.id.retry_button).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mRestService.getComicLatest(WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In the above example, in the WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE, I want the instance of the Callback anon class.

Obviously, I know that I could just make an instance variable in the Callback class that holds a reference to "this" and use it for the WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE, but I was hoping there might be a cleaner way, much like how we call Outer.this for non-anon classes.

Comment: Why are you doing this to yourself?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis haha, well, it's a good enough theoretical question, I guess.  It would look horrible with too much code and would be bad design as well in most cases, but I'd still like to know if it is possible.  Seems like I should know these things after using Java for so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a reference to `this` inside the outer anonymous class:

```
mRestService.getComicLatest(new Callback<Comic>() {

    private final Callback<Comic> outerAnon = this;

    @Override
    public void success(Comic comic, Response response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        mRetryFrame.findViewById(R.id.retry_button).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mRestService.getComicLatest(outerAnon);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the best answer.  I was just wondering if there were a way not to name the class at all.  Storing it into a reference variable works, too; good point.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it without the final variable. It's complicated with two anonymous classes. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, the reference variable in the first solution above is not initialized yet at compile time.  This will not compile.

Comment: You are correct, good catch. I edited the answer to reflect only the working solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to chain it further just like you started with Outer.this this should also work:

Outer.Inner.this

*Edit:
After reading further I see that I may have misunderstood your question, sorry if that is the case.*